# Is $\{(m+ka,n+kb) : m,n,k\in\mathbb Z\}$ dense in $\mathbb R^2$ if $a,b\notin\mathbb Q$?

Tags: real-numbers

Can anyone prove here that for $a,b\in\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$ we have that the set
$$
\{(m+ka,n+kb) : m,n,k\in\mathbb Z\}
$$
is dense in $\mathbb R^2$? I know that the projections onto the coordinate axes both are dense in $\mathbb R$, but I cannot prove the density of the set in two dimensions.

EDIT: It was shown below that the set is not dense in the following cases: (1) $a+b\in\mathbb Q$ and (2) $\exists t\in\mathbb R : t(a,b)\in\mathbb Z^2$. The question is now: When *is* the set dense in $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: When you project, you lose a lot of information. Try the simple(r) case of finding a sequence converging to $(0, 1/2)$.

Comment: I cannot see why $(0,1/2)$ is so special...

Comment: What if $a=b$?..

Comment: It is special in the way that $0$ is an integer and hence more comfortable. Basically the same form of this is $(0, p)$, where $p$ is any number. It is also sufficient.

Also, Tim has a good point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}, a=1-x, b=x$, then the set is not dense.

In general, the set is not dense when $a+b\in \mathbb{Q}$.

When $a=b$, the set is also not dense. To see that, start with the square grid $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$, and then to get $\{(m+ka,n+kb) : m,n,k\in\mathbb Z\}$, you take the grid and add copies of it shifted by the vector $(a,b)$. When $a=b$ the copies move along the diagonal, and so all the points are on the diagonal lines, so it's not dense.

Comment: Can you show that it is not dense in the case $a = b$? I do not see it...

Comment: Thanks. You are right. So it depends on the angle of the line which is generated by $(a,b)$. I guess the set is dense if and only if this angle is an irrational multiple of $\pi$.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. I say that the set is not dense if and only if for some $t\in\mathbb R$ we have that $t(a,b)\in\mathbb Z^2$.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp That won't do. Let $a=\sqrt{2}/2, b=1-\sqrt{2}/2$, then there's no such $t\in\mathbb{R}$.