# When is $\{(m+ka,n+kb) : m,n,k\in\mathbb Z\}$ dense in $\mathbb R^2$ when $a,b\notin\mathbb Q$?

Tags: real-numbers, integer-lattices

I asked a very similar question already [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2326588/is-mka-nkb-m-n-k-in-mathbb-z-dense-in-mathbb-r2-if-a-b-notin-ma/2326605?noredirect=1#comment4789567_2326605). There I asked whether the set $\{(m+ka,n+kb) : m,n,k\in\mathbb Z\}$ is dense in $\mathbb R^2$ when $a,b\in\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$. The answer was: *Not in general*. For example the set is not dense if $a=b$ or if there exists $t\in\mathbb R$ such that $t(a,b)\in\mathbb Z^2$. I could generalize this to the following:

*The set is not dense when there exist $l_1,l_2\in\mathbb Z$ such that $l_1 a + l_2 b\in\mathbb Z$.*

My question is: Does the converse hold?

Comment: This is equivalent to whether (ka,kb) mod 1 is dense in $\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Z}$ and the answer is whenever $1,a,b$ are independent over $\mathbb{Q}$. Let me find a reference

Comment: @user426577 Hi, thanks. You mean $\mathbb R^2/\mathbb Z^2$, right? And what do you mean by "independent over $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: yes ofc $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \mathbb{Z}^2$. And I mean that $a$ is irrational and $b$ is irrational and there is no $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ so that $a=bq$ (I think that in this case they're not just dense they're equidistributed)

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/18174/independence-over-q-and-kroneckers-result

Comment: Thank you very much. So, my condition is also necessary for non-density. great!